# Is the anonymous feedback still accessible at mod-tools level?

Tags: support

I just remembered the anonymous feedback page (I saw it a year or more ago) and I wanted to take another peek before graduation raises the thresholds. But I can't find the link. Does it still exist for mod-tools level users?

Answer (score 2):

Aha! Yes. https://music.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/

Url formula discovered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247804/allow-access-to-anonymous-feedback-stats-without-10k-rep) (where you can also vote to lower the threshold for this feature).